# How to show Original HTML post after sanitizing in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing a Blog module, and sanitize the blog_post at INPUT with

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('blog_data', 'Blog Post', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|xss_clean');
```

Now that the input has been sanitized I have lost the HTML styling, Can anyone recommend a way to get the styling back to show the blog post in the original styling as posted by the user?

If sanitizing the HTML data at OUTPUT (instead of INPUT) is a good practice then how do people retain the original styling?

For example, wordpress is storing HTML data of user blogs in original form with all styling tags intact (raw HTML). But it must be sanitizing it during output. Then how does it retain the original styling?

How to do it in codeigniter? Please help I have been banging my head for 3 days now .:/

Followup- @Damien Pirsy -

Original code obtained from sql-db:

```
<img src="http://localhost/lok/images/63a9f0ea7bb98050796b649e85481845/11342974127.jpg" style="cursor: default; height: 208px; float: left; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px; ">
```

Output Obtained on web-browser:

```
<img src="http://localhost/lok/images/63a9f0ea7bb98050796b649e85481845/11342974127.jpg"  default; height: 208px; float: left; margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px; ">
```

Comment: You alredy said that...store the "raw" html, and then only sanitize what you output; the original, raw html isn't touched by this. Malicous at it may be, html can't do any harm inside a db. So just don't xss_clean it in validation, clean it when outputting

Comment: @Damien - The "style tag" from the "img src" is removed by xss_clean which in turn corrupts the image styling.

Comment: ...so don't xss_clean it...Did you read my comment?

Comment: @damien The html code updated in the question is the output obtained during xss_clean @ the output w/ raw data stored in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "htmlpurifier" with CodeIgniter. The img src styling is unaffected now.